# ignore failing, non-OS drives?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Context:
Remotely located machine with desktop ubuntu 12.04, 2 data drives, 1 OS drive, all specified in /etc/fstab.

Issue:
During boot one SATA data drive does not respond,
and machine will not boot, waits indefinitely for manual input, S for Skip, R for repair, required by Ubuntu.

Question:
The goal is to have Ubuntu always boot as long as the OS drive is fine,
*not* halting on failed data drives.

How to reach this goal ?

Comment: That sounds like something that should be configured in the BIOS as far as I can see. It isn't a U&L question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to login as root then comment out all **/etc/fstab** entries pointing to partitions from the failed data drive. It *might* be necessary to remount the / partition in read-write mode (if it's mounted read-only and you can't save the file the 1st time, re-try after remounting).

When you log out the system will automatically reboot and *should* come up normally (minus the failed drive mounts).

To avoid future non-essential drive failures from preventing the system from booting you could take them out from fstab and mount them when needed, either:

- manually
- using **autofs** (automatically mount them when attempts to access
  them are made and unmount them after some idle time): http://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/09/how-to-configure-autofs-in-linux-and.html (many other references out there).

I find autofs very useful for cases like yours, but especially for NFS partitions.

Comment: The machine does not accept my remote ssh login attempts while it is halted due to the faulty drive.

Comment: Expected - the failed drive causes the boot process to stop way earlier before starting the SSH service. You need to be on the 'console' - where you see the prompts. Hm, the edited question suggests ubuntu customized the automatic fsck (on other linuxes you typically see "give root password for maintenance" and you can login as root). Try to use S (skip) and see if it progresses to a point where you can login as root and apply the suggested solution.

Comment: I have no console. The machine is remotely located, half way across the country. I never want this to happen again, hence I need a way to force Ubuntu to boot and ignore faulty non-OS drives.

Comment: I have fsck = 0 for data drives in /etc/fstab.  
Only the OS drive has fsck =1.

Comment: k, remote machine - the console is where the machine "waits indefinitely for manual input, S for Skip, R for repair" (I'd guess some remote kvm solution or via some other human on site) - that's where the actions need to be done.